# Using JavaScript to have a text line cycle between various text

Tags: javascript, cycle

The idea is to have the subheader under the header cycle between text endlessly on page load.

Example:

**HEADER**

SUBHEADER 1

wait one second

**HEADER**

SUBHEADER 2

wait one second

**HEADER**

SUBHEADER 3

etc.

HTML:

```
                    <header class="hero-title hero-box">
                        <h1>Ninety9Balloons</h1>
                        <h2>Entertainment</h2>
                       <div class="sub-header">
                            <h3>Editing</h3>
                            <h3>Color</h3>
                            <h3>VFX</h3>
                            <h3>Motion Graphics</h3>
                        </div>
                    </header>
```

For one second EDITING will be under Entertainment, then it cycles to COLOR, then VFX, etc. and repeats back to EDITING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```html
<header class="hero-title hero-box">
  <h1>Ninety9Balloons</h1>
  <h2>Entertainment</h2>
  <div class="sub-header">
    <h3 id="dynamic-sub-head">Editing</h3>
  </div>
</header>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```js
const subHeads = ['Color', 'VFX', 'Motion Graphics', 'Entertainment'];
let displayIdx = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  document.getElementById('dynamic-sub-head').innerHTML = subHeads[displayIdx];
  displayIdx += 1;
  if (displayIdx >= subHeads.length) {
    displayIdx = 0;
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: That works perfectly! I've been googling various bits of it to try and understand it better.

You created a variable with an array of the various strings.

Not sure what the displayInx is for though.

setInterval repeatedly calls the function with a 1 second delay.

Grabbing the HTML element and changing the text with the array items.

...If the display index is greater than the length of the array it repeats back to the first item back in the array, right?

Comment: Correct  displayIdx is the index of the Array; it identifies which item of the Array to display when the interval hits, and just like you said once it counts up to the end of the Array, it jumps back to zero. It will run indefinitely so long as the interval is in memory.